# Ao dar rollback em transição, resetar o id para o último id realmente inserido

Tags: php, mysql

Quero evitar de ter pulos no auto incremento do `id`, caso haja algum erro e eu faça `rollback` na minha transação. E ao mesmo tempo quero assegurar que não aconteça nenhum erro caso eu altere o auto-incremento, em caso de acessos simultâneos e etc.

Exp:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A melhor opção seria algo assim?:

```
ALTER TABLE sales_order AUTO_INCREMENT =(SELECT MAX(id_sales_order)+1 FROM sales_order)
```

Queria aproveitar a deixa e saber se existem práticas melhores  para salvar dados em um banco de dados

Sei que a partir do momento que se fala em melhores práticas, a chance da minha pergunta ser negativada e fechada é grande, porém queria uma sugestão de usuários mais experientes, se possível.

Minha estrutura comentada:

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
//Abro a conexão
$db = new PDO('ok');
//Inicio da transação
$db->beginTransaction();
//Seto para pegar qualquer erro de sql
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sales_order (total_price) VALUES ($id,0)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    //Pego o último id inserido
    $lastId = $db->lastInsertId();
    //Gero um hash com esse id utilizando a biblioteca
    $hash_id = generate_hash_id($lastId);
    $sql = "UPDATE sales_order SET hashed_id ='".$hash_id."' WHERE id_sales_order = ".$lastId;
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    if ($e != ""){
        //Seto erro 500 no header da resposta
        header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 500 Internal Server Error");
        //Salvo em um arquivo .txt o log do erro com a data e hora
        date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Sao_Paulo' );
        $filename = 'log-errors.log';
        file_put_contents( $filename, '[START]'.PHP_EOL.date( 'r' ).PHP_EOL.$e.PHP_EOL.'[END]'.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
        //Realizo rollBack de todas alterações feitas na transação
        $db->rollBack();
        die();
    }
}
//Dou um commit em todas alterações feitas na transação
$db->commit();
echo '{"status":200}';
```

Fonte da biblioteca: [Hashids](http://hashids.org/)

Toda

Comment: Não diretamente resolvendo seu problema, mas só para alertar: normalmente uma aplicação não deve depender da existência de IDs contínuos. O objetivo da autonumeração não é esse. Se quiser implementar um controle sequencial, precisa de um outro mecanismo, ou tabela auxiliar. IDs auto-gerados são para integridade e consistência do banco, e não das regras de negócio da aplicação-cliente.

Comment: Rs vou levar isso em consideração @bacco 

Comment: Essa questão do id pulando em cada transição não feita sempre foi um toque meu, se não for possível ou não for praticável, fica como dica mesmo

Comment: Sua solução do alter table funciona, só que pode ter problemas com concorrência. Precisaria fazer um lock geral para não acontecer de ter 2 alter com dado errado. Além disso, se estiver com transação aberta, vai ser um rolo danado. A não ser que você centralizasse o gerenciamento dos IDs em um processo único (por exemplo, um PHP rodando em background com exclusividade nessa reorganização). Não consigo ver uma maneira simples e "automática".

Comment: Outra coisa que você pode fazer é esperar a transação dar certo, e guardar um ID sequencial numa coluna independente, mas precisa estar atento para processos paralelos não pegarem o mesmo número. Como é que faz nesse caso se deletarem o registro 10 quando vc estiver no 89?

Comment: A ideia proposta é que nenhum registro jamais seja deletado, algo que poderia se enquadrar na pergunta, levando em consideração isso que você disse(quando deletar um registro), é quando (nunca, possivelmente e provavelmente, mas levando em consideração que aconteça) os ids estourarem na última opção possível, ele voltasse e pagasse cada id disponível.
Sei que no Oracle tem modo de se fazer esse gerenciamento, na outra empresa que eu trabalhava o dba tinha aplicado essa regra

Comment: Reciclagem é uma maneira bem simples de nao deixar buraco, mas ai tem desdobramento: se eles precisam estar na ordem de lançamento (normalmente quando não pode ter buraco, costuma ser necessário manter a sequencia também). Outra maneira simples é nessa parte do programa, usar lock total mesmo, assim você só tem uma transação por vez. Aí nem precisa de autonumeração, só dum MAX( coluna ) + 1 - só que aí tem que ser um sistema que não dependa de paralelismo nas inserções (é viável em sistemas de pouca concorrência no insert)

Comment: Na modelagem, foram criados campos de "criado em" e "alterado em" em cada tabela, então pra controle de ordem de lançamento acho que a solução de manter os buracos não seria um problema, minha dúvida agora como seria setar para utiliza-los quando os ids sequenciais acabarem